# internal server error 500 with htaccess in custom directory

Tags: .htaccess

I use mysql dumper to work with my database. The program prompts me to create folder protection. After typing name and password, program created htaccess. and password files in dumper's directory. 
Unfortunately after I am not able to access the same url - internal server error. Permissions are - folders 755, files 644.  Apache error log shows no record. Path in file is correct. Basicaly in any folder where I try to put this htaccess file becomes unavailable with internal server error. What can be the problem? Thank you.

This is content of newly created htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine off
</IfModule>
AuthName "MySQLDumper"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/data/web/xxx/web/dump/msd1.24.4/.htpasswd"
require valid-user
```

Comment: Check your apache error_log for the problem. No need to guess.

Comment: @PanamaJack already checked but there is nothing. No message at all. Same goes for access.log

Comment: I might be wrong, hence the comment but I didn't think you can use a relative filepath for `AuthUserFile`? Also, you have three leading dots in your filepath `...` which looks like a problem

Comment: @Darragh it is not relative path, I replaced full path. Fixed now

Comment: @user1031743 Do you mean the issue is fixed or your example is fixed?

Comment: @Darragh example is fixed, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I had to enable authn_file and auth_basic modules in apache for this to work.